# CSS scale and translate issues. How do they do it properly?

Tags: javascript, css, transform, scaling

This is all mobile browser related, not desktop.
I'm trying to make a certain div to maintain its dimensions  relative to device screen.
So when the user zoom in/out, the DIV and its content (image) will stay the same, nor blurry, not pixelated.
It's very hard to do it XBrowser. I thought that I was almost there but then I saw it on iPhone 5S and every time I used my method, it came out blurry.

I wish it could look like they did it on this [website](http://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/n/nirvana/all_apologies_crd.htm). Please try it on mobile and wait for the footer splash to appear.
They made it so well, no matter which device you have, the splash in the footer remains the same.
Could you please help me on establishing a similar splash behavior?
I am this close to give up :(

Here's what I tried so far. A bit of code and pseudo code:

1. I get the current viewport width and height
2. I get the scaleW and scaleH by dividing the vpWidth and vpHeight by screen.availWidht and screen.acailheight accordingly.
3. I have a problem on choosing which scale to put in the CSS so if it's portrait, i use the scaleW or else, scaleH (Is this a good method?).
4. I calculate the left and top of the element in this way:
5. `left = (vpWidth-width*scale)/2; top = (vpHeight-height*scale)/2;` where width and height are the div's width and height
6. I calculate the 'translate' like this: `translate = -((1 - scale) / 2) * 100;` I saw it in the website that I talked about and frankly, it makes sense.
7. I then apply this code to the div style: `-webkit-transform:translate(<%= translate + '%' + ',' + translate + '%' %>) scale(<%= scale %>) translateZ(0px);` and of course add the left and top properties.
8. I'm pretty novice in CSS :( so i learn from code and examples. Not novice in coding at all.

Comment: anything you tried? we will help you from where you are stuck

Comment: Fair enough :) I have edit the question.
@j08691 - thanks for editing.

Comment: Hi Again,
I need this pretty urgent so if it's not well understood, I hope if you can share your method to place a DIV which will maintain its physical size upon zooming in all devices, XBrowser as shown in the website that I have attached.
Thanks again.